# Why Does "HTML + ToC" Successfully Export Notebook With Hidden Input and "HTML" Fails?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, hide, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions, export-to-html

When I hide all the input cells using nbextensions on jupyternotebook, only export as "HTML + TOC" works. I try exporting to HTML, yet the input code appears. What is the logic behind this? I have no TOC so it says None at the top of the page, which I am okay with.

Chat GPT's response makes sense, but an additional input would be great.
Chat GPT explains, "to summarize, the behavior you're observing is likely due to the interaction between nbextensions, nbconvert, and the specific export options. Using "HTML + TOC" might involve additional logic to respect the visibility settings applied by nbextensions, while the standard "HTML" export may not have that awareness by default."

I was expecting the code to be hidden when exporting as HTML.

Comment: maybe you would have to check source code for this function. Maybe author(s) didn't expect that someone will need to hide something when it export `HTML`.